# "Automatically" creating non-member wrappers for C++ member functions

Tags: c++, wrapper

I have a class with a bunch of member functions which do some mathematical operation and return a result. For example:

```
class Foo {
public:
  double f(double);
  double g(double);
  double h(double);
  // ...
}

double Foo::f(double foo1) {
  // ...
}
// and so on
```

At several points in the program I'm working on, I need to numerically integrate some of these functions. The numerical integration routine I'd like to use has the signature

```
extern "C" double qgauss(double (*func)(double, void*), void* data,
                         double a, double b);
```

and from what I've been reading it seems that the best way to pass the member functions to the integration routine is to create wrapper functions:

```
double f_wrapper(double x, void* data) {
    return ((Foo*)data)->f(x);
}
```

But with about a dozen member functions `f`, `g`, `h`, etc. to wrap, and perhaps more to be added later, this gets pretty repetitive. Can (or perhaps *should*) I use a template or macro or something to condense the amount of code I have to write in order to create these wrapper functions?

---

As an aside, the solution I'm currently using is to reimplement the integration routine as a C++ function template that accepts the object parameter directly:

```
template <class C> double qgauss(C* obj, double (C::*func)(double),
                                 double a, double b) {
  // ...
}
```

but this involves large-scale duplication of code, which I don't like. If anyone has a better solution than either creating wrapper functions or implementing a C++ version of the integrator, I would be interested to hear it and I can ask a separate question if that would be more appropriate.

Comment: If there is only one instance of class Foo, can you just make all the methods static?  Then the function becomes Foo::f(x)  instead of foo->f(x)?

Comment: I could, but the functions `f` etc. do need to access member variables in `Foo`. So if I made them all static, the syntax for accessing variables would be all messed up because I'd have to explicitly refer to the instance, which kind of defeats the point of using a class in the first place.

Comment: I would use a macro for that.  It would be fairly tame compared some of the ones I've written.

Answer (score 2):

You could try it with templates:

```
template <class C, C::*Func>
double wrapper(double x, void* data) {
    return ((C*)data)->*Func(x);
}

qgauss(&wrapper<C, &C::f>, data, a, b);
```

Now, I haven't tried this, and there may be some issue because you want the address of a function which is a template--and worse yet I think you technically need an `extern "C"` function.  If the above is indeed a dead end, I think you should just use macros, as after all this is C programming you're doing at this point, and macros are natural for that.

Comment: Template are resolved at compile time, and in terms of linkage, extern "C" just prevents name-mangling. This looks like a good solution

Comment: @Dave Calling conventions may also differ between `extern "C"` and C++, but that depends on compiler and compiler settings. E.g. Visual Studio's stack cleanup difference between __cdecl and __stdcall (the latter is default when /Gz is present on commandline): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58.aspx

Comment: Good point. Would `__cdecl double wrapper(...)` be sufficient?

Comment: This didn't work when I tried just copying and pasting it, but maybe a bit of tweaking is necessary?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised.  Perhaps you could post the errors you got?